# Pass variable to another Vue.js component

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I am trying to pass a variable from one component to another, in order to perform a query in Firebase from that component. I have an array that brings me the id of the document and I assign it to a variable, how can I take this value from another component?

```
   <v-layout wrap row >
    <v-flex xs12 sm6   v-for="product in products" :key="product.id" >
      <v-card>
        <v-card-media :src="product.src" :key="product.nombre" height="200px">
        </v-card-media>
        <v-card-title primary-title>

          <v-spacer/>
          <v-chip label color="pink" text-color="white">
              {{product.nombre}}
          </v-chip>         
          <v-btn color="green" dark @click="seePrd(product.id)"  >
                 Ver
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-title>

      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>

</template>

<script>
    import { db } from '@/main';
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';


    export default {
        name: "show-products",        
        data () {
            return{
                products: [],
                idSelected:''                
            }
        },
        methods:{          
          seePrd(valId){
             this.idSelected = valId  
            this.$router.push('/administration/ShowProduct');  




          }

        },
        mounted() {                   
            var today = new Date();
            var dd = today.getDate();
            var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
            var todayHour = today.getHours();
            var todayMin = today.getMinutes();
            if (dd < 10) {
                dd ='0' +dd;
            } 
            if (mm < 10) {
                mm = '0' + mm;
            }
            today= yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd
           var  todayTime = todayHour + ':' + todayMin        

            db.collection('products').where("limitDate",">=", today).onSnapshot(snapshot => {

                for (var i =0 ; i < snapshot.docs.length; i++){                   
                    db.collection('products').doc(snapshot.docs[i].id).get().then(doc => {
                        var url;
                        var prdName;  
                        var id;

                        if (doc.data().limitDate == today && doc.data().limitHour < todayTime){  
                      } else {
                        url = doc.data().urls[0];
                        prdName = doc.data().productName;
                        id = doc.data().pid;
                        const datos = {
                           src: url,
                           nombre: prdName,
                           id: id
                        }                       

                          this.products.push(datos)                                    

                      }                      

                    })
 }

          }, (error) => {
            console.log('listener products pagination off...');
          }          );


        },








    }


</script>
```

I need the way to access idSelected from the new component to be able to query Firebase and have all the data in that document

Comment: You could replace the v-btn component with router-link component and pass the product id as a route parameter like <router-link :to="`/administration/ShowProduct/${product.id}`">ver</router-link>. If you'd rather keep the button then you could use a template literal in your $router.push which would pass the id as a route param as well. Like this: this.$router.push(`/administration/ShowProduct/${valId}`);

Comment: Okay, but how i can access to that value from the other component?

Comment: "How can I access that value from the other component" -> See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode and https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-props/app.js. Another way would be to use a Vuex store (https://vuex.vuejs.org/)

Comment: You can also use event bus. https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/